# reply for wrong results console.log javascript split

Tags: javascript, if-statement, split

[image]

When you can't find split as in the image

VM439:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined at

> If split returns a null value, I want the console to respond 'error',
> but if it does, it should print completed.

I want it to write an 'error' response instead of a red-banded error in the console, how can I do it?

Code:

```
token = document.head.innerHTML.split('"encryptedTokenJarContents":"')[1].split('"')[0];
if (token === "") {
alert('error');
}else {
alert('completed');
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `split` to parse innerHTML? Use DOM methods to get what you want from the elements.

Comment: I think that it is not the first split that is causing the problem but the second split. It is probably because the property "[1]" of the array just does not exist. If you wanted the first element, you have to write (arr[0])[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#referring_to_array_elements "zero - indexing"].\

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try...catch`.

```
let token = "";
try {
    token = document.head.innerHTML.split('"encryptedTokenJarContents":"')[1].split('"')[0];
} catch(e){}
if (token === "") {
    alert('error');
} else {
    alert('completed');
}
```

Comment: That's what I wanted. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one try/catch statement to your code.
All errors that occurs will go to the catch statement, where you can show your error message.

```
try{
    token = document.head.innerHTML.split('"encryptedTokenJarContents":"') [1].split('"')[0];

    alert('completed');
}catch(error){
    alert('error');
}
```